# Can density be spatially dependent?

Tags: density, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I was reading Gardiner's Handbook of stochastic Methods of Physics, Chemistry and Natural sciences. In page 4, he was discussing Brownian motion and referencing Einstein's own work on the subject. It caught my attention that part of the derivation defined number of particles per unit volume as a function of position and time. Density being a function of time is very intuitive to me as you can have particles leaving or entering the system as time goes. What is isn't clear to me is how can density be dependent of space Since any point in space is just a point, how can you define density at a point in space? I attached a screenshot from the book for reference.

[image: Screen shot from the book of Gardiner]

Comment: *Since any point in space is just a point, how can you define density at a point in space?* Do you understand how we define instantaneous velocity at an instant in time? An instant is just a point in time.

Comment: Can you explain more? It is not intuitive to me because for velocity there is acceleration that causes it to change from one point in time to another, but in the case of density why would it change in space?
For example, when I think about a cube, its density to me is a property that is independent of the point you are looking at in space.

Comment: Think about the atmosphere. Its density decreases as you go up toward outer space. The air gets “thinner”, even on a mountaintop, and it becomes harder to breathe because there are fewer oxygen molecules per cubic centimeter.

Comment: The core of the Earth has a higher density than its crust.

Comment: Your bones have a higher density than your muscles, so the human body has a non-uniform density.

Comment: Thank you! That totally escaped my mind.

Comment: Density in crystals is dependent on direction and location. In physics classes we were always getting "assume a spherical chicken" or it's equivalent. There was "assume the space is homogeneous and isotropic" meaning it has the some properties everywhere and the same properties in every direction. This admonition is needed because reality is not so ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density at a point is the limit as the volume goes to zero $\lim_{V\rightarrow 0} m(V)/V$.   You can think specifically of a sphere whose center is at the point got the volume.